# Change html page whit event onchange using a list

Tags: javascript, html

**i got this list on my index.html**

```
<select id="selectFaq">
    <option selected>Selecciona un FAQ</option>
    <option value="JavaFAQ.html">Java FAQ</option>
    <option value="netFAQ.html">.Net FAQ</option>
    <option value="PhpFAQ.html">PHP FAQ</option>
</select>
```

**the propose of the next code its change the courrent page when the user change the default value on the list:**

```
window.onload = configuraSelect;

function configuraSelect() {
    document.getElementById("selectFaq").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("selectFaq").onchange = cambiaPagina;
}

function cambiaPagina() {
    var elementoSelect = document.getElementById("selectFAQ");
    var nuevaPagina = elementoSelect.options[elementoSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (nuevaPagina != "") {
        window.location = nuevaPagina;
    }
}
```

but, on the sentence

```
var nuevaPagina = elementoSelect.options[elementoSelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

the code didn't return any value, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a spelling error?

Instead of this:

```
var elementoSelect = document.getElementById("selectFAQ");
```

Try this:

```
var elementoSelect = document.getElementById("selectFaq");
```